# How to debug cache in Drupal?

Tags: php, caching, drupal-7

I have an issue on a Drupal 7 website, where blocks that should not be cached are getting cached. How do I debug this kind of issues? Do I have an easy way to know which block is getting cached and with which cid?

The block that gets cached is defined like this in the `hook_block_info`:

```
$blocks['product-info-block'] = array(
  'info' => t('Product info'),
  'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
);
```

In the DB there is no trace of this specific block so I suspect it is being cached as part of something else, is there an easy way to figure that out?

Note: I did not develop this so I know little to nothing about the structure, I am just doing some bugfixes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your APC cache. And obviously, check your local cache.

Also, if you're using a proxy server that has caching enabled, ask the admin to exclude your site from caching.

**Update 09:36 GMT-6 20120804:**

*Okay, so no APC cache...* I know it's dirty, but you could grep the site (or at least your theme/module folder) for "product-info-block" or some of the text that shows when the block is displayed. It's possible the block is stored in an addon module or theme.

I would also **check your modules** screen for any block or performance related modules, and finally **check your permissions** for your anonymous and authenticated users. *(For example, a block access module could be showing a cached block to anonymous users but the live one to logged in users. This also happens from Drupals' cache which can be configured under the Performance section of the Drupal admin screen.)*

Comment: APC cache is not even enabled.
The cache issue is not on the client side, but quite obviously on the server side, in particular inside Drupal. I have no proxy server or admin between me and the Internet.